# Axis 2 and rampart issue while adding cutom header to the request

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis, rampart

```
<soapenv:Envelope> 
<soapenv:Header>    
      <cor:india>test</cor:india>
     </soapenv:Header>

<soapenv:Body>
.
.
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

     OMFactory omFactory =OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
    OMNamespace omNamespace = omFactory.createOMNamespace("http://example.com/...", "cor");
    OMElement header = omFactory.createOMElement("india", omNamespace);
    header.setText("test");
    stub._getServiceClient().addHeader(header);
```

I wanted to add the custom header to the soap request which was using the axis 2 and rampart.
but below is the exception i am getting

```
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Error in extracting message properties
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartMessageData.<init>(RampartMessageData.java:379)
    at org.apache.rampart.MessageBuilder.build(MessageBuilder.java:61)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:65)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Error in converting SOAP Envelope to Document; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPHeaderBlock
    at org.apache.rampart.util.Axis2Util.getDocumentFromSOAPEnvelope(Axis2Util.java:191)
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartMessageData.<init>(RampartMessageData.java:270)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPHeaderBlock
    at org.apache.rampart.util.Axis2Util.getDocumentFromSOAPEnvelope(Axis2Util.java:141)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: i got the same error . but i do not find out error please give sample app to me

Comment: @sureshmanda, Are you doing the same operation of adding an additional header information eg:"<cor:india>test</cor:india>" in the soap request via axis 2 ?

Comment: yes, but i am not follow this kind.

Comment: You have to add the name space and add the content to header its shown in the Answer section.. here is the code of it.




OMNamespace ns = factory.createOMNamespace("http://google.com", "cor");
hdr.addHeaderBlock("india", ns).setText("value here");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add header using the tips provided here [Example Custom Headers](http://www.keith-chapman.org/2008/10/axis2-adding-custom-soap-headers-to.html) and where as you are using rampart to engage then you are like to face the above problem.

Solution for that is to add your own module.xml in the META-INF and add the out flow where you are adding your custom header

```
<module name="test" class="exampleClass">

    <OutFlow>

            <handler name="handle" class="exampleClass">
                <order phase="Security"  />
            </handler>
        </OutFlow>
</module>
```

==================================================================================

```
public class exampleClass AbstractHandler implements org.apache.axis2.modules.Module {

public InvocationResponse invoke(MessageContext ctx) throws AxisFault {

SOAPEnvelope env = ctx.getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader hdr = env.getHeader();

SOAPFactory factory = (SOAPFactory) env.getOMFactory();

OMNamespace ns = factory.createOMNamespace("http://google.com", "cor");

//SOAPHeader head = factory.createSOAPHeader(env);

hdr.addHeaderBlock("india", ns).setText("value here");

return InvocationResponse.CONTINUE;
}


public void applyPolicy(Policy arg0, AxisDescription arg1) throws AxisFault {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public boolean canSupportAssertion(Assertion arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public void engageNotify(AxisDescription arg0) throws AxisFault {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void init(ConfigurationContext arg0, AxisModule arg1) throws AxisFault {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void shutdown(ConfigurationContext arg0) throws AxisFault {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

} }
```

================================================================================

In the client engage your module before rampart like

```
Options options = serviceClient.getOptions();
serviceClient.engageModule("test");

options.setProperty(RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_POLICY,loadPolicy("policy.xml"));
serviceClient.engageModule("rampart");
..
```

..